# ¿Cómo llamar datos por rangos en mysql y php?

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un boton de cargar más pero no sé cómo hacer para que al principio me muestre 10 elemntos de una tabla y cuando ponga cargar más, se carguen otros 10 elemento más e igual tengo etiquetas que van 1 2 así eso quiere decir que cunado muestre 20 elementos ponga 2 y me salgan otros 20 elemntos.

Comment: Buenas Vinicio. Yo te recomendaria usar datatables, te ahorran mucho trabajo en estas cosas. De todas formas echale un vistazo a [ask]. Si sigues estos consejos sera mas facil ayudarte.

Comment: eso va para de la mano con el SQL, revisa Top 10, top 20...

Comment: Sin ver tu query no puedo mas que darte una respuesta generica. Pero se usa LIMIT en su version de dos parametros.

Comment: justamente a Limit me refería mi estimado @gbianchi, la costumbre de jugar con SQL Server :D

Comment: muchas gracias me sirvio mucho.....con el limit valio a la perfección mil gracias

Comment: @VinicioMoyaAlmeida si tu pregunta anterior no era valida, eliminala y abre una nueva pregunta. No edites y cambies totalmente tu pregunta, porque asi no funciona el sitio. voy a revertir tu edicion.